# Running a webpack bundled JS library with "umd" module system in Nodejs throws error: "self" is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

Recently I have been developing a JavaScript library and now I want to publish it on npm.
Then I learned that I've to use a package bundler. So I started learning webpack and followed their guide **Authoring a library** form the docs.

In their guide they suggested using `umd` module type to support all module systems so I used "umd". But when I tried to run (via **importing**) the generated bundle file in **Node.js**, it throws an exception saying **"`self` is not defined"**! Then I opened the bundled file and found that there is a variable named `self` but I don't know what is its purpose.

Whatever long story short, then I tried `commonjs` and `commonjs2` module type and published a test package and tried it in both **react** and **node** environment and it worked perfectly. Sadly then it didn't work in **browser** environment with the **<script>** tag. Now my question is **what module type should I use?**

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    library: {
      type: "commonjs", // umd, commonjs2, ....
    },
  },
};
```

Here is my project structure

```
|- /dist
|- /src
|- package.json
|- webpack.config.json
```

Webpack versions:

```
"webpack": "^5.53.0"
"webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
```

Thanks in advance. I highly appreciate your time on StackOverflow <3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of time wasting I found the answer in a github issue of webpack.

I can use `library.type: "umd"` but I just have to add the following in my webpack configuration.

```js
module.exports = {
  output: {
    globalObject: 'this' // This line was missing
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks goodness for reporting your discovery here, saved me a lot of time poking around! I will learn to not fully trust Webpack's documentation.